# Как упомянуть пользователя telegram по id

Tags: telegram-bot, golang

Подскажите, как встроить ссылку типа `tg://user?id=var_ID`,где var_ID переменная с ид пользователя в  сообщение по типу

```
msg.Text=(update.Message.From.FirstName+", "+player_info.text_predict)
c.Bot.Send(msg)
```

где вместо просто имени пользователя будет ссылка с его именем при нажатии на которую откроется его профиль?

Comment: [fmt.Sprintf](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#Sprintf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию `Sprintf` пакета `fmt`

Чтобы всё сработало, нужно включить разметку. Передать `MarkdownV2` в поле `parse_mode`.
https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style

```
// формируем ссылку
name := update.Message.From.FirstName
id := 12345
name = fmt.Sprintf("[%s](tg://user?id=%o)", name, id)

// встраиваем
msg.Text=(name +", "+player_info.text_predict)
c.Bot.Send(msg)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]